# Rate of convergence of a given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

[image]

Need the first option, whether it is correct or not.

For $\beta =1$ we have, $x_{k+1}=2^{-1+\log_2 x_k}$ .Using recurrence we have, $x_{k+1}=2^{-(k+1)}x_0$. Then $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty}\left|\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}\right|=2^{-1}$.

So the sequence $\{x_k\}$ converges to $0$ linearly and rate of convergence is $2^{-1}$.

So the first option is incorrect.
Am I correct ?

Comment: your treatment of the case $\beta=1$ seems to be correct.

Comment: Set $y_k=(-\log_2(x_k))^{1/\beta}$. Then $y_{k+1}=...$

Comment: @LutzLehmann For the 1st option $\beta =1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm not getting your point. My 1st question is whether my calculation and method are correct or not ? If not thn why?

Comment: Sorry, yes, what you wrote is correct, my comment was a hint on the next step which is not too different from what you did for the special case.